# 1004 Error when trying to write a string to a cell on the Active Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

The following simple test function is always generating a 1004 error message:

```
Function MyTesting() As String
  On Error GoTo myErrorHandler
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Testing"
  MyTesting = "Done"
  Exit Function

myErrorHandler:
  MyTesting = Err.Number
End Function
```

I have put the function call in cell "A1" of an otherwise empty worksheet of a workbook that's Macro enabled, with the .xlsm extension. Only cell "A1" is set to "Protected" and the worksheet is not protected. I have also looked through the File -> Options and set everything to as open/dangerous as Excel will allow!

Using breakpoints I have confirmed that it is:

```
  ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Testing"
```

that causes myErrorHandler to be invoked. I have also tried many different variations, all having the same problem, including:

```
  Range("A2") = "Testing"
  Cells(2,1).Value = "Testing"
  ActiveSheet.Cells(2,1) = "Testing"
```

Can anyone suggest anything further I can try, to stop getting this 1004 Error?

Comment: A function called from a cell on a worksheet cannot in itself change the value in another cell.

Comment: How did you put the function in A1? within the Change event or what?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787

Comment: Thanks, that explains the problem. It just took a day of tearing my hair out, thanks to Microsoft's use of generic and meaningless error codes and descriptions!